# malloc-ing a char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have a struct that contains a char array like so:

```
typedef struct{
  char *name[128];
} arr;
```

I thought I read earlier that the correct way to allocate memory for this would be:

```
arr thisOne;
thisOne->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
```

However, this results in an error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[128]’ from type ‘void *’
```

Trying to cast the return from malloc doesn't help, as then I simply get a char * when I need a char *[128]. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note: "Trying to cast the return from malloc doesn't help". That is better for you to know than you may think, because in C [you shouldn't be casting `malloc` regardless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: this line: char *name[128]; allocates an array of char pointers. when what you want is just a single char pointer, like so: char * name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you're trying to do;

Just a few things to clear up. If you declare an instance of `arr`. Accessing a member is performed with the `.` operator. For example; `thisOne.name = X`. The following; `thisOne->name` will work if `thisOne` is a pointer to an instance of `arr` in memory.

Okay. Based on your implementation, it seems like the call;

`malloc (sizeof (char) * 128)`

is allocating memory of 128 characters (128 * 8 bits) into memory. This is fine, if the structure is like so;

```
typedef struct {
    char * name;
} arr;
```

However your structure is in fact declaring an array of 128 char pointers, which is conflicting with your `malloc` statement. If this is actually your intent then your malloc call should be like so;

`thisOne.name = (char **) malloc (sizeof (char *) * 128);`

using the structure below.

```
typedef struct {
    char ** name;
} arr;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Well, `name` is an array of pointers to char. You probably want a string, thus a single pointer to char:

```
typedef struct{
  char *name ;
} arr;


arr thisOne;
thisOne.name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
```

In this scenario including the maximum size of the string would be sensible:

```
typedef struct{
  char *name ;
  size_t max ;
} arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

thisOne.name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (128+1));

+1 for '\0'

Comment: This looks correct, but can you add some more explanation of how it works?